# Contacts does not sync, while Reminders and Calendar do

Tags: icloud, contacts

I have two devices: iPhone (12 mini, iOS 16.7.2) and a MacBook Air (OS 12.6.7). iCloud is the only Contacts repository on my devices. When I create or edit a contact on one device, the change does not appear on the other. Moreover, only the change made on the iPhone appears on iCloud.com; changes made on the Macbook do not appear on iCloud.com. Contacts created on iCloud.com show up on the iPhone but not the Macbook. Reminders and Calendar do, however, sync just fine across both devices and iCloud.com. It therefore appears that the MacBook Air is not correctly syncing Contacts with iCloud.

I have double- and triple-checked the settings on the Macbook Air (  System Prefs>AppleID and System Prefs>Internet Accounts and Contacts>Preferences...>Accounts), per the instructions at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203521 .

Summary: Why are my Contacts not syncing with the Macbook Air, while Reminders and Calendar are syncing just fine?

Thanks!